# Trying to download PDF file from laravel API and vuejs front but always gets empty pdf file

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, vue-resource

this problem has got me stuck for days now.
Am consuming an API built in laravel 8.
A PDF file is created using laravel domPDF and is already saved in a directory.
All am trying to do is download it using the Vue js but when i download, i get a blank PDF file.
Header response-Type is set to 'blob' in both API and VueJS

Code from Laravel API;

```
  public function download_invoice(Request $request)
    {
        $invoice_id = $request->input('invoice_id');
        $path = public_path('images/pdf').'/'.$invoice_id.'.pdf';
        $headers = [
              'responseType' => 'blob'
           ];         
        return response()->download($path, $invoice_id.'.pdf', $headers);

    }
```

Code from VueJS;

```
 downloadInvoice(item){
        this.$http.post('downloadinvoice', item, {headers:{
               Authorization:`Bearer ${this.token}`,
               responseType: 'blob',
          }})
       .then(res=> {
        const fileName = item.invoice_id+'.pdf';
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data], { type: 
        'application/pdf' }));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
       })
      }
```

Sample console response from API;

```
%PDF-1.7
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R >>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
/Kids [6 0 R
]
/Count 1
/Resources <<
/ProcSet 4 0 R
/Font << 
/F1 8 0 R
/F2 9 0 R
>>
/XObject << 
/I1 10 0 R
>>
>>
/MediaBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890]
 >>
endobj
4 0 obj
[/PDF /Text /ImageC ]
endobj
5 0 obj
```

Can't post the entire response from the console, keeping it simple.

Comment: What sort of response header is `responseType: blob` supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

You are sending  this.$http.post('downloadinvoice', item, ( Item from front end not invoice_id ?
and you are getting `$request->input('invoice_id')`; in your back-end code

Comment: item is the json table id that holds an object of the invoice.

Comment: but you are using invoice_id in back not item.id . invoice_id does not exists